# use pre-compile views with RequireJS (can-compile)

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, ejs, canjs

i used can-compile NodeJS module that compiles CanJS EJS views into a single JavaScript file for lightning fast production apps in my project. (i use canjs, requirejs, ejs.js for templates):

i followed these instructions to set my grunt task https://github.com/daffl/can-compile

my Gruntfile.js :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    cancompile: {
        options: {
            version: '1.1.8',
            wrapper: 'define(["can/view/ejs"], function(can) { {{{content}}} });'
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['**/*.ejs', '!node_modules/**/*.ejs', '!www-built/**/*.ejs'],
            dest: 'www-built/js/views.production.js'
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        //configuracion uglify
        options: {
            mangle: false,
            compress: {
                drop_console: true
            },
            preserveComments : false
        },
        js: {
            files: [{
                cwd: 'www-built/js/',  // ruta de nuestro javascript fuente
                expand: false,    // ingresar a las subcarpetas
                src: 'views.production.js',     // patrón relativo a cwd
                dest: 'www-built/js/'  // destino de los archivos compresos
            }]
        }
    }

});
/*carichiamo i moduli*/
grunt.loadNpmTasks('can-compile');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

/*registriamo il task*/
grunt.registerTask('default', ['cancompile']);


};
```

the grunt task work, and it create the single js file compiled, but when i run the require build it doesn't include the generated file with the views in production.

i got this error :

```
can.view: No template or empty emplate:js/app/common/calendar/views/init.ejs
```

i created a file views.production.js into the directory of my project with content :

```
define('views', function() {});
```

then in my build.js file application i put this :

```
 "paths" : {
    "app" : "../app",
    "tools" : "../../../tools",
    "jquery" : "jquery-2.0.3.min",
    "jquery-ui" : "plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min",
    "jquery-ui-touch-punch" : "plugins/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min",
    "bootstrap" : "bootstrap.min",
    "underscore" : "underscore.min",
    "can" : "can",
    "aria" : "aria",
    "models" : "../app/common/models",
    //folder directory for documentation
    "doc" : "../doc",
    "async" : "require/async",
    "goog" : "require/goog",
    "propertyParser" : "require/propertyParser",
    "google-api" : "aria/google_api/google-api-engine",
    "google-maps" : "aria/google_api/google-maps-engine",
    "collaboration" : "../app/collaboration",
    "swipe" : "plugins/swipe2",
    "animend-transend" : "plugins/jquery.animend.transend",
    "jquery-validate" : "plugins/jquery.validate.min",
    "jcrop" : "plugins/jcrop/js/jquery.Jcrop.min",
    "spin" : "plugins/spin",
    "ftscroller" : "plugins/ftscroller",
    "owl-carousel" : "plugins/owl.carousel.min",
    'shared_resource' : '../shared_resource',
    'views' : '../views.production'
}
```

then in a commons.js file for the application i made a require :

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'aria',
    'app/common/error_handler',
    'app/common/vocal',
    'views'
], function (jQuery, AriaTouch) {
```

my application attempt to call ejs files :

```
GET http://local.bst.prod/js/app/timeline/sidebar/bookmark/views/submenuBookmark.ejs 404 (Not Found)
common.js:4 Uncaught can.view: No template or empty 
template:js/app/timeline/sidebar/bookmark/views/submenuBookmark.ejs
```

Comment: Why are you using uglify and not [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)? If you use it as described in the [Loading with RequireJS](https://github.com/daffl/can-compile/#loading-with-requirejs) section it will be included in the build and should work.

Comment: You are right , I will modify this part , but the problem is that It doesn't include the compile file on the project, do you have an Idea ??

Comment: You can easily test it by compiling and adding `define(['views'], function() {});` in your project. That should load the compiled views. If it does not work your paths are probably wrong.

Comment: could you tell me where should i save the file views.production.js ? thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as the location where you run the compilation is the same you load your views from in your app.

Comment: I have the ejs files in different directories because I made a multiple page  application, every one has its entry point main.js , is this a problem ?

Comment: Do I need to require views in another Files ?

Comment: I think it is easier if you [submit another issue](https://github.com/daffl/can-compile/) with your setup in the repository.

Comment: Ok I'll do it !! Thanks